# Javafx TableView with custom row color using CSS

Tags: javafx, tableview

I would like to update my TableView rows color depending on the data in the cell. In the oracle documentation, there is an example with the ListView, I would like to do the same thing with a Tableview, I think I have to customize my cellfactory but I do not understand how it works.
Here is the link : http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html

My TableView is defined in my FXML file and in my controller I have the following code:

```
@FXML public TableView<TableData> tableView;
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
    //Depending on data change row color ?
    tableView.setItems(data);
}
```

Comment: See [this search result](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavafx%5D+or+%5Bjavafx-2%5D++or+%5Bjavafx-8%5D+tableview+row+color+is%3Aquestion)

Comment: I see, by using PseudoClass and CSS it can be done but there is something I don't understand, I set my CSS as following :.table-row-cell:credit {
    -fx-background: #008000;
} In my eclipse, I got a warning saying it does not know -fx-background, but it works. However the text color is white. If I replace it by -fx-background-color, the warning disappear and the text is back to black but by using -fx-text-fill to custom the text color, it does not work. Did I forget to do something ?

Comment: There is no "-fx-background" property. Fo this refer to [this CSS guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html). To change the color of text again see content of modena.css. You may need to try to style .table-cell. And importantly, update your question (and title) according to your last comment. So someone else can post an answer below instead of in comments. As you also already saw that this site works that way.